Universe apps not showing in app center Ubuntu 24.04
It looks like apps from the Universe repository are not showing in the new App Center in Ubuntu 24.04. Universe is selected in software sources and I'm searching in Debian packages.
For example: searching for Synaptic in App Store gives 'No results found'. Installing in the terminal with apt is working though.
Isn't App Center showing apps from Universe? Lots of other apps are missing when searching but can be installed with apt.
I've tried it on three machines with two fresh installs of Ubuntu 24.04 and one upgraded beta install.
Is this a bug in App Center?

I'll suggest you use a package manager if you want to look for packages (I like aptitude but I prefer using a terminal over a normal GUI app, but synaptic is probably preferred by most)

"I've tried it on three machines with two fresh installs of Ubuntu 24.04" You seem to have met the "is it reproducible?" threshold. Please report the bug to the Ubuntu Bug Tracker. (AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker) Review the list of bugs for similars first -- duplicates waste time and effort.

The new app center in Ubuntu does not show any apps in the official APT repositories. It only shows snap apps.
If you want an app store for regular APT apps, install gnome-software with
sudo apt install gnome-software

Moreover, gnome-software also supports installation of snap and flatpak apps.
If you don't have universe enabled, you can enable it with
sudo add-apt-repository universe


OK thanks. But why then can you search for Debian packages ('Filter by Debian packages'). Will Debian packages be added to App Center in the near future?

I really don't know that. All I know is, app center does not allow installing locally downloaded .deb packages, and its previous version did not show any APT packages at all. Maybe they recently added the ability to search through Debian packages, but as you found out, it is buggy.

With the update to Snap Store 0+git.ec3fa65 (latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04) in Ubuntu 24.04 the problem is solved! App Center now is showing Deb-files.
